# AWS CodePipeline BuildAction not detecting buildspec.yml secondary artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to use secondary artifacts to separate the files from the web page from the cdk generated Stack files. but the BuildAction from the pipelines is not detecting the secondary artifacts that separate the web files from the Stack files.

I've tried following the recomendations on the AWS docs relating to buildspec.yml as well as multiple sources and multiple outputs, but can't get it to work.

here's my cdk code for the build action.

```
const buildStage = pipeline.addStage({ stageName: 'Build'});
        const buildOutputWeb = new Artifact("webapp")
        const buildOutputTemplates = new Artifact("template")
        const project = new PipelineProject(this, 'Wavelength_build', {
            environment: {
                buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_3_0
            },
            projectName: 'WebBuild'
        });

        buildStage.addAction(new CodeBuildAction({
            actionName: 'Build',
            project,
            input: sourceOutput,
            outputs: [buildOutputWeb, buildOutputTemplates]
        }));
```

here's the section relating to the Build Action from the generated stack file

```
{
            "Actions": [
              {
                "ActionTypeId": {
                  "Category": "Build",
                  "Owner": "AWS",
                  "Provider": "CodeBuild",
                  "Version": "1"
                },
                "Configuration": {
                  "ProjectName": {
                    "Ref": "Wavelengthbuild7D63C781"
                  }
                },
                "InputArtifacts": [
                  {
                    "Name": "SourceOutput"
                  }
                ],
                "Name": "Build",
                "OutputArtifacts": [
                  {
                    "Name": "webapp"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "template"
                  }
                ],
                "RoleArn": {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "WavelengthPipelineBuildCodePipelineActionRoleC08CF8E2",
                    "Arn"
                  ]
                },
                "RunOrder": 1
              }
            ],
            "Name": "Build"
          },
```

And here is my buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    S3_BUCKET: "wavelenght-web.ronin-ddd-dev-web.net"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - npm install typescript -g
      - npm install -D lerna
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm run release
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
  post_build:
     commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  secondary-artifacts:
    artifact1:
      base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      files:
        - 'packages/website/dist/**/*'
      name: webapp
      discard-paths: yes
    artifact2:
      base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      files:
        - '*/WavelengthAppStack.template.json'
      name: template
      discard-paths: yes
```

Comment: Any CodeBuild errors?

Comment: CLIENT_ERROR: no definition for secondary artifact webapp in buildspec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
turns out that the name attribute in the secondary artifacts doesn't change the identifier.
my buildspec.yml artifacts now look like this.

```
artifacts:
  secondary-artifacts:
    webapp:
      base-directory: packages/website/dist
      files:
        - '**/*'
      name: webapp
    template:
      base-directory: packages/infrastructure/cdk.out
      files:
        - 'WavelengthAppStack.template.json'
      name: template
```

notice that now instead of `artifact1:` and then all data for that artifact it is `webapp:` and then all the data.

Answer (score 1):

`webapp` and `template` secondary attracts (from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.name)):

> Each artifact identifiers in this block **must match an artifact defined in the secondaryArtifacts** attribute of your project.

In what you've posted in the question I don't see any evidence of the secondary outputs being defined in your build projects. Which probably explains why you get errors about "no definition".

Comment: The problem with that is that it is for a CodeBuild Project that is not used in pipelines. there is no attribute for the PipelineProject referring to the secondary artifacts

Comment: I tried adding the secondary artifacts and I got this error.
A Project with a CodePipeline Source cannot have secondary artifacts. Use the CodeBuild Pipeline Actions' `outputs` property instead